# Windows Server 2008 R2: Weekly network failure

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, troubleshooting

Thought I would throw the question on here, as I'm not a seasoned sysadmin...

Every Thursday (or there about) at no particular time, the server becomes unresponsive to its usual network operations (i.e. AV updating, not allowing RDP connections, applications not receiving network traffic, etc.) however pings (to and from the server) are replied to, and DNS requests complete from the server when other operations fail.

There is not much in any of the application logs relating to this failure, which makes me believe it's a server error. When I check the System logs, we typically see the following errors around the time of failure:

1. 5719 - NETLOGON
2. 1054 - GroupPolicy (..Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller..)

We have also seen the following, when I left a RDP session active:

1. 56 - TermDD (Terminal server security layer detected an error in the protocol stream)

After we reboot the server, every thing seems to work correctly.

I did a packet capture, but I can not see anything obvious.

Any thoughts/tips welcome,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does the problem last if you don't do a reboot? Or does it never go away unless you reboot?

Comment: Longest we've left it would be hours. But as the server is being used we can't leave it for testing purposes.

Comment: Is the server fully patched? I've ran into similar issues where a MS patch fixed the problem.

Comment: @Rowell, yes we recently did a round of windows patching on our servers, but this problem has been going on for a while now. I'm just doing Firmware updates.